# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'info'

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, nomachine-nx

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_edgelist('webpages.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
print(nx.info(G))
```

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'info'
```

print(nx.info(G)) without the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just `print(G)` to get the graph properties

Answer (score 0):

`info` method has been [removed from networkx 3](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/release_3.0.html)

You should consider accessing the Graph properties directly instead

```
print('Number of nodes', len(G.nodes))
print('Number of edges', len(G.edges))
print('Average degree', sum(dict(G.degree).values()) / len(G.nodes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Print (G) works fine in NetworkX 3.2.1
[image]